# Как обновить текущие данные в реквизитах справочника, получая данные из массива?

Tags: 1с

Получаю данные из БД в JSON формате, и засовываю их в массив. Как можно обновить данные в справочнике, данными лежащими в массиве?

```
Результат =  Ответ.ПолучитьТелоКакСтроку("UTF-8"); 
    Чтение = Новый ЧтениеJSON; 
    Чтение.УстановитьСтроку(Результат); 
    Массив = ПрочитатьJSON(Чтение); 
    Для Каждого ЭлементМассива из Массив Цикл 

    КонецЦикла; 
    Чтение.Закрыть(); 
    КонецЕсли
```

Answer (score 0):

Элементы массива - это же объекты? Если да, то:

```
ЭлементМассива.Записать()
```

Если документ, то, возможно:

```
ЭлементМассива.Записать(РежимЗаписиДокумента.Проведение)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в полученных данных есть код или наименование элемента справочника, который нужно изменить, то можно прямо в объектной модели найти ссылку по коду или наименованию, потом получить объект, изменить его реквизиты и записать. Все это нужно делать в том цикле, как у вас в вопросе.
Пример вставки в цикл обхода массива, если есть код элемента справочника:

```
ТекСсылка = Справочники.НазваниеСправочника.НайтиПоКоду(ЭлементМассива.Код);
Если Не ТекСсылка.Пустая() Тогда
    // элемент есть в 1С - обновляем
    ТекОбъект = ТекСсылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
    ТекОбъект.НужныйРеквизит = ЭлементМассива.НужныйРеквизит;
    ...
    ТекОбъект.Записать();
Иначе
    // элемента нет в 1С - создаем новый
    ТекОбъект = Справочники.НазваниеСправочника.СоздатьЭлемент();        
    ТекОбъект.Наименование = ЭлементМассива.Наименование;
    ТекОбъект.Код = ЭлементМассива.Код; // если есть автонумерация не нужно писать код
    ТекОбъект.НужныйРеквизит = ЭлементМассива.НужныйРеквизит;
    ...
    ТекОбъект.Записать();
КонецЕсли;
```

Естественно, на место НазваниеСправочника и НужныйРеквизит подставляете правильные данные, с которыми работаете.